# How do I save the last element and expand to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page has pagination (button to show more), which loads the blocks every time.

There is a reload code like this. At the moment the reloading is working, but by clicking on the button the page will hide to the very top, not to the last item that is loaded. How to save the last block, load the content and scroll to it. An example by clicking on the link: https://tvoidv.ru/culture/.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#more-news', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var _url = $(this).attr('data-url');
  send = false; //убираем шумы
  if (_url && !send) {
    $.ajax({
      url: _url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        // включение прелоудера
        send = false;
      },
      complete: function() {
        // отключение прелоудера
      },
      success: function(obj) {
        send = true;

        $(".news-grid-list__mb").last() //Возвращаем последний div-элемент с классом news-grid-list__mb.

        $('#more-news').remove(); //удаляем текущю кнопку
        $("#get_news").append(obj['html']) //добавляе  готвую разметку

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(".news-grid-list__mb").offset().top //Скролл
        }, 1000);

        if ('show_more' == true) {
          $('#more-news').show();
        } else {
          $('#more-news').hide();
        } //добавляем кнопку если пришел флаг
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText + "\r\n" + xhr);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the issue on this site, not only on a third party site. When I click Run code snippet, all I see is an error about `$` not being defined. On the left of the snippet editing interface, there is a place where you can choose what version of jQuery you want to include.

Comment: Just use `scrollTop: $(".news-grid-list__mb").last().offset().top`

Comment: @Heretic Monkey An example of how it works now can be found at https://tvoidv.ru/culture/.

Comment: I know, I saw that in your question. Please read my comment again. I am not asking you for a link to working code. I am asking you to provide code that demonstrates the issue here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @skobaljic Tried your solution somehow does not work, you can insert into my code which is higher, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you know what no. of element you are going to add. From your website reference I can see 8. You can write something like this in success block after appending your content. You can add or subtract some offset (number) with top to match it perfectly.

```
var target = $("#get_news div:nth-last-child(8)")

$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1000);
```

Just copy and run directly in your website after loading more content, its working for me